# Nested If/Else control flow being executed when it shouldn't be - logical operations error probably

Tags: python, string, if-statement, logic

I've got this code:

```
def time24hr(tstr):

    if ('a' and ':') in tstr:
        if tstr[:2] == '12':
            tstr = tstr.replace('12', '00').replace(':','').replace('am','hr')
            return tstr

        elif len(tstr[:tstr.find(':')]) < 2:
        # If length of string's 'tstr' slice (that ends before string ':') is less than 2
            tstr = tstr.replace(tstr[:tstr.find(':')],'0' + tstr[:tstr.find(':')]).replace(':', '').replace('am','hr')
            # Replace one-character string with combination of '0' and this one-character string. Then remove colon, by replacing it with lack of characters and replace 'am' string with 'hr'.
            return tstr

        else:
            tstr = tstr.replace(':', '').replace('am', 'hr')
            return tstr

    elif ('p' and ':') in tstr:
        tstr = tstr.replace(':', '').replace('pm', 'hr')
        return tstr

    else:
        return "Time format unknown. Type correct time."
```

When i execute this code `print time24hr('12:34am')` it returns `0034hr` string as it should.
It works also for this `print time24hr('2:59am')`, returns `0259hr`. But when i type string with `12` in it, it automatically omits this part of code `if ('a' and ':') in tstr:` or this `elif ('p' and ':') in tstr:` and proceeds to this part:

```
if tstr[:2] == '12':
    tstr = tstr.replace('12', '00').replace(':','').replace('am','hr')
    return tstr
```

So no matter if i type `12:15am` or `12:15pm`, this code if finds the `12` in string, starts doing this above code. `print time24hr('12:15pm')` returns `0015pm` but should return `0015hr` and only for strings with `am` in it. Else, don't change `12` to `00` and return i.e. `1244hr` for `12:44pm`.

My question is, why those logical check `if ('a' and ':') in tstr:` and `elif ('p' and ':') in tstr:` aren't working?
This code is meant to be a solution for this quiz -> http://www.pyschools.com/quiz/view_question/s3-q8

==================================================================================

Thanks for helping me, with logical operations.

Also, i've completed above mentioned quiz and here's working code:

```
def time24hr(tstr):

    if (len(tstr[:tstr.find(':')]) == 2) and (tstr[0] == '0'):
        tstr = tstr.replace(tstr[0], '')

    if ('a' in tstr) and (':' in tstr):
        if tstr[:2] == '12':
            tstr = tstr.replace('12', '00').replace(':', '').replace('am', 'hr')
            return tstr

        elif len(tstr[:tstr.find(':')]) < 2:
        # If length of string's 'tstr' slice (that ends before string ':') is less than 2
            tstr = tstr.replace(tstr[:tstr.find(':')], '0' + tstr[:tstr.find(':')]).replace(':', '').replace('am', 'hr')
            # Replace one-character string with combination of '0' and this one-character string. Then remove colon, by replacing it with lack of characters and replace 'am' string with 'hr'.
            return tstr

        else:
            tstr = tstr.replace(':', '').replace('am', 'hr')
            return tstr

    elif ('p' in tstr) and (':' in tstr):
        if tstr[:2] == '12':
            tstr = tstr.replace(':', '').replace('pm', 'hr')
            return tstr

        elif len(tstr[:tstr.find(':')]) < 2:
            PmDict = {'0':'12','1':'13', '2':'14', '3':'15', '4':'16', '5':'17', '6':'18', '7':'19', '8':'20', '9':'21', '10':'22', '11':'23'}
            tstr = tstr.replace(tstr[:tstr.find(':')], PmDict[tstr[:tstr.find(':')]]).replace(':', '').replace('pm', 'hr')
            # Replace every "number" (which is string literally) with it's corresponding "number" in 24HR format, found in 'PmDict' dictionary. Then, as in above cases, remove colon ':' by replacing it with lack of character or space and then replace 'pm' with 'hr'
            return tstr

    else:
        return "Time format unknown. Type correct time."
```

I hadn't written this code according to the KISS rule, as you can see - 'cause it's a bit complicated, but works quite well IMO.

It can be tested here -> http://doc.pyschools.com/console

Cheers everyone and thanks for helping :)

Comment: Because this is not how the `and` operator works. It evaluates its operands and returns the one that determines the final result. `'a' and ':'` is `':'` because both (`'a'` and `':'`) evaluate to `True`. `0 and 'foo'` would result in `0` because `0` evaluates to `False`. The result is then passed to the `in` operator, so you get `':' in tstr`.

Comment: just a slight clarifcation to @FelixKling's comment : It doesn't necessarily evaluate both operands.  It only evaluates the right operand if the left operand is true-like. (This is referred to as `short circuit evaluation`)

Answer (score 6):

```
if ('a' and ':') in tstr:
```

is same as

```
if ':' in tstr:
```

hope this gives you insight to what problems seems to be.

probably replace with

```
if 'a' in tstr and ':' in tstr:
```

Comment: Why does `'a' and ':'` evaluate to `:`?

Comment: @arxanas -- because non-empty strings are true-like.  The `and` operator looks at the left object and asks -- Is this true-like?  If it isn't, it returns the left object.  If the left object is true-like, it returns the right object.

Comment: @arxanas Similarly `'a' or ':'` evaluates to `'a'`.

Comment: if this works then mark it as answer, then question will be marked as solved

Comment: Ok, I came up with proper idea and made the solution.
Solution is in updated question above. Cheers!

Comment: @mgilson What? I didn't undertood.

If operator looked at the **left** object, and determined it as `False` (or _not_ `True`), it should then determine **right** object as `True` (or _not_ `False`) and return it? And vice versa, right?

Comment: @spaffy -- In order for `and` to return a true-like result, **both** operands must be true-like.  If the first one isn't true-like, there is no sense in checking the second one.

Comment: Yeah, now i understand. But if both (or more) operands are true-like, the result will be operand placed most to the right, yes?

Answer (score 0):

Well your first check:

```
('a' and ':') in tstr
```

is only really checking to see if ':' is in tstr. Exactly why this is, I am not sure but if you run the `('a' and ':')` statement in interactive Python, you will see that it returns ':'.

Your second check has the same error.

Consider using

```
if ':' in tstr and 'a' in tstr:
```

and

```
elif 'p' in tstr and ':' in tstr:
```

Unfortunately Python can only be so English-like :)

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that your code checking for substring containment is incorrect: you are using `in` improperly. When you write

```
if ('a' and ':') in tstr:
```

It evaluates `('a' and ':')` first to get `:` and then checks `if ':' in tstr`. That's why the first `if` block keeps evaluating to true. This happens because `and` is a boolean operation, and `x and y` is equivalent to `x if bool(x) else y`. This expression is evaluated before you even get to the `in` check.

You would replace that code with

```
if ('a' in tstr) and (':' in tstr)
```

(and do similarly for the other check)

Answer (score 0):

You can generalize this testing for existence of multiple elements using `all`:

```
if all(ch in tstr for ch in 'a:'):
    etc...
```